# EnumChildWindows callback function in golang

Tags: go, user32

Using package lxn/win in main:

```
win.EnumChildWindows(hw, printme, 0)
```

Then after main:

```
func printme(HWND win.HANDLE, LPARAM uintptr) { //HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam
    spew.Dump(HWND)
}
```

I get:

```
.\test.go:40: cannot use printme (type func(win.HANDLE, uintptr)) as type uintptr in argument to win.EnumChildWindows

error:exit status 2
```

I don't understand the error message.

Comment: To rephrase the error, the `printme` argument is of type `uintptr`, and you're passing it a `func(win.HANDLE, uintptr)`.

Comment: The function requires a callback function. How would I convince the compiler?

Comment: You can't "convince" the compiler that a go function is a uintptr, because that simply can't work. What is `lxn/win`, and is there any documentation for using the `EnumChildWindows` function?

Comment: lxn/win is an interface to windows user32.dll. No examples of it's use other than the standard: [lxn/win](https://godoc.org/github.com/lxn/win#EnumChildWindows). I could ask on github.

Comment: If this is for a windows syscall, you probably need to use `syscall.NewCallback` (or maybe `syscall.NewCallbackDecl`, I don't know anything about windows.)

Comment: Thanks. The compiler took it but I couldn't get the function to print anything. I'll create an issue on github. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with:

```
win.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, syscall.NewCallback(printme), 0)

func printme(hwnd uintptr, lParam uintptr) uintptr {
    spew.Dump(hwnd)
    fmt.Printf("getWindowText: '%s'\n", getWindowText(hwnd))
    return 1 // true to continue
}
```

See [`lxn/win` issue 19](https://github.com/lxn/win/issues/19):

> The callback signature is wrong: it has to return a value of type `int32` (`C BOOL`) that is nonzero if the function should continue enumeration.
>   [See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
>
> For example, it could be:
>
> ```
> func printme(hwnd uintptr, lParam uintptr) int32 {
>     spew.Dump(hwnd)
>     return 1 // true to continue
> }
> ```